# Why doesn't this copy statement work?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I want to copy the contents from columns in one worksheet to another. Why doesn't this work:

```
srcWbk.Range("DN18:FN378").Copy trgtWbk.Range("DN18")
```

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: What are `srcWbk` and `trgtWbk`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you try to copy something in a `worksheet` and paste it to another, but you are using `Workbook` objects (`srcWbk` and `trgtWbk`).

**It should be `Worksheet` object instead** since you can't access to the `Range` property from a `workbook` object.

```
srcWbk.Sheets("YourScrSheetName").Range("DN18:FN378").Copy trgtWbk.Sheets("YourTrgtSheetName").Range("DN18")
```